# Windows disappeared from UEFI menu after installing Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I reinstalled Lubuntu on my computer and for some reason Windows 10 doesn't appear on my UEFI menu anymore. Grub doesn't recognize the partition either after I tried `os-prober` and `update-grub`. I can't find the file `bootmgfw.efi` in the EFI partition.

What should I do?

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: You've not provided any release details; Lubuntu curently has 3 supported installers selected by release & ISO used...   (*one of the installer options has had no update in 3 years so should be avoided if at all possible as was documented, being written for specific hardware and not uEFI, you likely didn't use it but without specific release details we cannot know*)

Answer (score 1):

Oops, looks like Lubuntu may have either formatted your EFI System Partition (ESP) or removed your boot files. You can restore it by using the following:

1. Boot your computer using a Windows 10 installation media or Windows 10 recovery disk. On the first screen, press SHIFT+F10 to enter Command Prompt.
2. Use the following commands:

```
select disk # (“#“ is your ESP that you will copy boot files to.)
assign letter=S (You may replace “S” with other letters which are not already used.)
exit
```

3. Use the command below to copy the boot files from the Windows partition to the EFI system partition and create the BCD store in it:

```
bcdboot C:\windows /s S: (“C” is the drive letter of the system partition and “S”  is the drive letter you assign to the EFI partition.)

exit
```

5. Restart your computer.
6. After the restart, boot into Lubuntu immediately. Open QTerminal (or LXTerminal, I don't use LXDE/Qt) or use tty (Ctrl+Alt+F2)
7. Update Grub using `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Please note:  We don't know the Lubuntu release, and `lxterminal` was last used six releases ago for the last time (18.04) with all subsequent releases using `qterminal`.